# Echo to all files matching pattern

Tags: linux, bash, pattern-matching, echo

I have some files in some directory.
For example:

```
/path/file1.out
/path/file2.out
/path/file3.out
/path/file4.out
/path/file5.out
```

Is it possible to write something to all of these files using echo with a single command?
I would expect something like

```
echo "asd" > /path/file*.out
```

but it is not recognizing the glob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to redirect to more files, you need to use a loop:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in /path/file*.out; do
   echo "foo" > "$file"
done
```

Or you can use `tee` that will output to stdout at the same time:

```
shopt -s nullglob
echo "foo" | tee /path/file*.out
```

Note that `shopt -s nullglob` is important so that you don't create an undesired file if there are no files matching your pattern.